# Wevtutil to output only new event logs

Tags: powershell, events, event-log, readeventlog, wevtutil

I run the command `wevtutil qe Application /rd:false /f:text` and  I get an output as shown below. After sometime new event logs could have generated and I want to read only these new event logs i.e. Event[2],  Event[3], Event[4] etc.

How can I use `wevtutil` tool to generate only these new event logs?

Event[0]:

- Log Name: Application
- Source: Microsoft-Windows-LoadPerf
- Date: 2016-04-21T23:15:16.832
- Event ID: 1000
- Task: N/A
- Level: Information
- Opcode: Info
- Keyword: N/A
- User: S-1-5-18
- User Name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
- Computer: WIN-IONOGQTF9O5
- Description: 
  Performance counters for the WmiApRpl (WmiApRpl) service were loaded successfully. The Record Data in the data section contains the new index values assigned to this service.

Event[1]:

- Log Name: Application
- Source: Microsoft-Windows-LoadPerf
- Date: Date: 2016-04-21T23:15:13.097
- Event ID: 3011
- Task: N/A
- Level: Information
- Opcode: Info
- Keyword: N/A
- User: S-1-5-18
- User Name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
- Computer: WIN-IONOGQTF9O5
- Description: 
  Unloading the performance counter strings for service WmiApRpl (WmiApRpl) failed. The first DWORD in the Data section contains the error code.

Answer (score 0):

weventil is not PowerShell so I was mislead. However, you could just do this:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Newest -After ( Get-Date ).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: this command doesn't work for me. -Newest needs a parameter like -Newest 100 to retrieve the latest 100 events. How can I select all new events without specifying the number.

Comment: Why don't you clear your event logs after you check them? Otherwise there is no way to record which ones you have checked and which ones you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

/rd:false will read the oldest first so if your looking for newest it may not be the best query.

I'm not aware of a read/unread tag for eventlogs, you could create a custom object and add one but that may not be the best way to go around it.

You can also do the below

```
$lastRanDate = "2018-11-30T17:20:55" ##import from a txt file
$date = Get-date -UFormat %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
##Get's current date and formats as following example 2018-12-01T17:17:45
$difference = New-TimeSpan -Start $lastRanDate -End $date
##Calculate difference between start time and end time
$difference = $difference.TotalMilliseconds
wevtutil epl Application "C:\Users\Pipastrilo\Desktop\appTest.evtx" /q:"*[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= $difference]]]"
## exportLog logName Path query(TimeCreated between current and HowManayMillisecondsAgo


$lastRanDate = $date
##export $lastRunDate for future searches
```